# non primitive recursive algorithms having polynomial time verification?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, np-complete

i think the title speaks for itself,

since the defining trait for NP class is that - they are the set of decision problems verifiable in polynomial time by a deterministic Turing machine.

thus it shouldn't matter if the algorithm computing the function belongs to any particular class - exp or factorial, even non-PR , as long as they are computable, but i am unable to find any specific example.

if there aren't any known such algorithms or problems, can it be proven that they atleast should exist ?

Comment: "computing the function" - computing which function?

Comment: computing the function which is supposed to be in NP

Comment: It is known that NP is subset of EXPTIME - every problem in NP can be solved in exponential time. Just iterate over all potential solutions (there are only exponentially many) and check each of them.

Comment: Please do not rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information. The body of your MSE questions should be self-contained. As for the mathematics, it is far from clear what you are asking.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53144/5038, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4743796/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

So let say you have an algorithm A that takes an input I and after some computation gives an output O.

Let say you have an algorithm V that can verify A, meaning that it takes an input (I, O, C) and compute in polynomial time (of the size of I) an output B such that **for at least one** C, if A(I)=O then V(I,O,C)=True

*We say that C is a certificate*

But if V computes in polynomial time (of the size of I), then the size of C is bound by a polynomial P (of the size of I). As for all couple I, O such that A(I)=O, there is at least one C, we can try all C of size lower or equal to P(|I|).

Note this is the same for O.

So for any I, the complexity of finding O is bounded by some exponential of a polynomial. (We try all possible O and C bounded by a fixed polynomial. Note that for decision problem, it's less work as O is a boolean)

So A can have any complexity (you can always add useless complexity), but there exist an algorithm computing the same thing as A that will be bound by some exp(P(s)).